# I am newbie to Programing and I trying to slowly Learn Python in Blender

Tags: python

HI I am new to programing I came across
this site to get me started

http://b3d101.org/en/pymove3d-python-3dworld/the-python-console/

I was wondering if anyone know of some common cheet sheets of standard Python Languages that is use all the time?

Comment: All the Blender specific operators and API reference are available at https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/

Comment: IMO, learning Python and learning Blender's API are two different things. Going through Blender's API if you have no programming (or Python programming) knowledge may be the hard way. Try to learn Python's basic first, there are many Python programming courses/tutorials on the web. But you can use Blender's environment to run most (not all as some modules are not included) Python programs.

Comment: Thank You I didnot know that I so glad you point that out to me I am taking a very basic Python 3 for babies on UDemy  so Blenders Python is call Blender API I notice from the built in Python in Blender is running Python 3.5.2  I wondering in what ways are they different if you donot might me asking I am still learning